# How to update only some values in spring config file

Tags: java, spring, yaml

is there any simple way how to update only some values in spring config file?
I am using .yml config file where user can set passwords in plain text or encrypted passwors. I would like to have command in my CLI application, which encrypts all passwords, but does not overwrite whole file (does not delete user comments from config file).

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask on a programming website, I assume that a program is considered a simple solution. The only thing that needs to be invariant is the indexing of the actual value to update.

First install `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package), which will preserve your comments etc on round-trip

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.util import load_yaml_guess_indent

yaml = YAML()

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fp:
    data, indent, bsi = load_yaml_guess_indent(fp)

# adjust this
data['path']['to']['password'] = sys.argv[2]

with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as fp:
    yaml.dump(data, fp)
```